# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out error when trying to read from table

Tags: java, jsoup, socket-timeout-exception

I'm working on coding a program that will go and retrieve the price of a person from a table on a website. The code gets a last name and searches the table for that name before returning the price (a different column) whenever I run it I get a java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

This is the code I'm using to query the website

```
public String price(String lastName) throws IOException
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    Elements rows = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");;

    for(Element row : rows)
    {
        Elements columns = row.getElementsByTag("td");
        String lastName = columns.get(0).text();
        String price = columns.get(2).text();
        if(lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
        {
            return price;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: So your read timeout is too short. Increase it.

Comment: @EJP Any suggestions on how to do that? A quick Google search suggested `Connection timeout(int millis)` but I'm not sure where I would place that in my code.

Comment: No, that sets the connection timeout. I don't know anything about JSoup but the default socket read timeout in Java is infinite so somebody somewhere must have changed it in JSoup.

Comment: That would be my guess as well. @martynas managed to provide a solution to your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: @EJP Comment from [iManage user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3643213/imanage-user): "apparently in Jsoup "Connection.timeout(int millis)" actually sets the timeout for both connection and read, according to the documentation:

Connection timeout(int millis) Set the request timeouts (connect and read).

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(60*1000).get();
```

or...

```
Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
```

Comment: I would guess that the `connect(url").get()` is a typo after he deleted the actual url. As the code was, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: A read timeout isn't a connection-related error. It can only happen if the connection has succeeded.

Comment: I mistakenly left a stray " in my code, it's been edited to how it is in my code. It's now been updated

Comment: That looks more plausible.

Comment: No problem. Please let me know which one did actually work for you so i can update my answer.